# Mockito mocking out native methods?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, java-native-interface, mockito

I am writing JUnit tests with the Epson SDK which uses a native ARM library. Here is the cut down class (for brevity):

```
package com.epson.eposprint;

public class Builder {
    private native int eposAddText(long l, java.lang.String s);
    public void addText(java.lang.String data) throws com.epson.eposprint.EposException { /* compiled code */ }
}
```

I need to ensure `addText()` is called. However, since I'm not running the unit tests through the Android emulator (and shouldn't be) it is unable to link up the ARM:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no eposprint in java.library.path
    at ...
```

Here is the test:

```
@Test
public void unformattedText() throws Exception
{
    Builder builder = mock(Builder.class);
    EpsonReceiptTranslator translator = new EpsonReceiptTranslator(builder);
    translator.execute(getXML("<text>foo bar</text>"));
    verify(builder).addText("foo bar");
}
```

Is there a way I can stub off all those natives, or just disable it from trying to link against the ARM library?